# maven jar reference in a war in a jar

Tags: maven, jar, war, ear

Hi All,

I am novice maven, and I know bare minimum to just run an existing project.
Below is my scenario :

Scenario :
There is an ear EAR1, there is a war in it, say WAR1. There are lot of jars in WAR1.

There is a specific jar in WAR1 say JARBuilt which is a custom code and is being packaged as jar. This is being used by code in WAR1.

Now JARBuilt needs few jars for it, and yes these are added in JARBuilt's pom.xml

I am able to generate the entire ear without any problem, but later when I refer to one of the jars ( put in JARBuilt pom ), in run time , the code is not able to identify the jar required.

Can you please guide me to what could be the possible missing part.

Thanks,

Comment: I take it that your EAR has a WAR file which has all the JARs (including the custom built one) inside the WEB-INF/lib. If not, you should explain it further by posting the directory structure.

Comment: Yup they are inside WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1):

Including A Third Party Library In EAR

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
           [...]
           <modules>
             <jarModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>                 
             </jarModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Read also this example [Excluding Files From the EAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/excluding-files-from-ear.html). This is about excluding, but the example is good for you. Simply try adding jar dependencies to EAR.